# Installing ansible in old RedHat 7

Tags: linux, python, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, ansible

I'm trying to install Ansible in a old RedHat. I have already update all packages using yum.

```
> sudo yum install ansible
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ansible.noarch 0:2.8.4-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: PyYAML for package: ansible-2.8.4-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python-httplib2 for package: ansible-2.8.4-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python-jinja2 for package: ansible-2.8.4-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python-paramiko for package: ansible-2.8.4-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python2-cryptography for package: ansible-2.8.4-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python2-jmespath for package: ansible-2.8.4-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package PyYAML.x86_64 0:3.10-11.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libyaml-0.so.2()(64bit) for package: PyYAML-3.10-11.el7.x86_64
---> Package ansible.noarch 0:2.8.4-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python2-cryptography for package: ansible-2.8.4-1.el7.noarch
---> Package python-httplib2.noarch 0:0.9.2-0.2.el7 will be installed
---> Package python-jinja2.noarch 0:2.8-7.rhel7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-babel >= 0.8 for package: python-jinja2-2.8-7.rhel7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python-markupsafe for package: python-jinja2-2.8-7.rhel7.noarch
---> Package python-paramiko.noarch 0:2.1.1-0.10.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python2-pyasn1 for package: python-paramiko-2.1.1-0.10.el7.noarch
---> Package python2-jmespath.noarch 0:0.9.0-1.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ansible.noarch 0:2.8.4-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python2-cryptography for package: ansible-2.8.4-1.el7.noarch
---> Package libyaml.x86_64 0:0.1.4-11.el7_0 will be installed
---> Package python-babel.noarch 0:0.9.6-8.el7 will be installed
---> Package python-markupsafe.x86_64 0:0.11-10.el7 will be installed
---> Package python-paramiko.noarch 0:2.1.1-0.10.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python2-pyasn1 for package: python-paramiko-2.1.1-0.10.el7.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ansible-2.8.4-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python2-cryptography
Error: Package: python-paramiko-2.1.1-0.10.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python2-pyasn1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Checking which version of Python is installed we have:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

How can I proceed to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried installing **python2-cryptography** and **python2-pyasn1**?  Which version of RHEL 7?  There are like 5 different releases.

Answer (score 0):

In first instance try to search among the yum repo

```bsh
yum search python | egrep  "pyasn|cryptography"
```

By this way your are going to search among the repo the packages that you need.

If they are not listed, than you can try adding the `epel` repos and the `centos-extra` repo.